# Plot/Convert an expression coming from sympy: Taylor series with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, sympy

i´am trying to plot the function sin(x)/x and a taylor approximation of it.
i use python 3 and pyzo - the first plot works but i have problems converting the series coming from the sympy module to an numpy expression that would work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import x

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)/x #first function
plt.plot(x, y, 'k') #this is working fine

### this is a code that removes the "0(x**something)" part of 
the series at the end
```

i found it here http://pastebin.com/ZNQakWP7

```
def series(expr, x, x0, n, removeO=False):
"""
sympy bugs avoided
"""
# expr_series = expr.series(x, x0, n)
# return expr_series.removeO() if removeO else expr_series
expansion = list()
for t in expr.lseries(x, x0):
    p = t.as_coeff_exponent(x)[1]
    if p < n:
        expansion.append(t)
    else:
        break
if not removeO:
    expansion.append(sp.O(x**n))
return sp.Add(*expansion)
### my code continued ####

y_t=series(sp.sin(x)/x,x,0,6,removeO=True)
```

if i look at y_t now i get this approximation

```
out: x**4/120 - x**2/6 + 1
```

Now i try to convert this to numpy in order to plot it as i did with the first function.

```
f_t = lambdify(x, y_t,modules=['numpy'])
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100) #i do this because x has
#been a symbolic variable before

plt.plot(x, y_t, 'b') #this is where the problem occurs
```

i get the first plot also a second error message:

```
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\pyzo2013_0_2_2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2832, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\pyzo2013_0_2_2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 3998, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
```

How can i achieve my idea to plot something coming from sympy?
Another idea i had was to convert the sympy out from the series to a string and then parsing this somehow to a numpy expression. I would be thankful for any help here!

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is that this:

```
plt.plot(x, y_t, 'b') #this is where the problem occurs
```

should be something like:

```
plt.plot(x, f_t(x), 'b')
```

`f_t` is the lambdified series, so it is a callable function that evaluates its argument.

I used [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) in the following example, and it works for me:

```
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import sin, series
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


func = sin(x)/x
taylor = series(func, n=6).removeO()

evalfunc = lambdify(x, func, modules=['numpy'])
evaltaylor = lambdify(x, taylor, modules=['numpy'])

t = np.linspace(-5.5, 5.5, 100)
plt.plot(t, evalfunc(t), 'b', label='sin(x)/x')
plt.plot(t, evaltaylor(t), 'r', label='Taylor')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Here's the plot generated by the script.

[image]